# How to get images url from html to java

Tags: android, html

Hello i'm tring to get the url's from **Bing** images. i.e [this link return cat images](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cat&FORM=HDRSC2)
how can i get only the .png url's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If bing supplies an API, then you should use that.

If it does not, then you get the .html file and parse it. Last time I did something like this, I used [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) library.